# Implementing top-level dynamic paging with VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm trying to build a simple web app with VueJS.  Until now, I've been able to follow [the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/).

### My Problem

I want to implement a generic page template that fetches the page metadata from my database.

However, pages are at the top-level of the navigation (`/`), so I can't use Vue route parameters to dynamically fetch the content from my database, because some of the pages have their own templates.

### What I've Considered...

I've considered doing the following to get around the problem:

- Implementing top-level parameter like this...

`{ path: '/:slug', component: User }`

..but this doesn't work for some reason.

- Using a `slot` in the page component for the custom content, and just creating a new component for every page, but I want to stay [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

...but I don't want to have to create a new component for every page.

### My Question

How do you implement top-level paging with a database backend in VueJS?  Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: what is  "top-level dynamic paging"?

Comment: You can use the :slug, but within your component, you willneed to watch for changes in the parameter.  When you detect a change, you can fetch new information for the requested slug from your server.  Since a change in a route parameter does not trigger a new route, your component is not update; watching for changes within the component will get you there.

Comment: @divine "top-level dynamic paging" means loading page content into a template from a database, wherein the pages happen to be at the top level (the root) of the domain.

Comment: @DavidHeremans to be clear, I don't want to replace the Vue Router functionality for pages that don't utilize the standard page template.  Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Sure - you set up one route per component that provide your template, and make the identifier a parameter.
/pages/:id -> route to component Page.vue and handle there
/someotherpage -> route to whatever component you want.

Comment: Yeah I get that: the issue is that I don't have **anything** before the page slug.  For example, there is no /page/*, it's at the root (i.e. top level) of the domain.  Do you see my problem?

Comment: @Squagem you need to render data in webpage by fetching that data from database, is it?

Comment: @divine yes, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: @Squagem did you try using vuejs lifecycle hooks?